# SharedPreferences returning empty

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code what runs each time a Fragment is loaded

```
Log.d("SP::getAll", sp.getAll().toString());
sp.storeValue(SP.STRING, KEY_TYPESANDCLASSES, s, TimeHelper.YEAR);
Log.d("SP::getAll", sp.getAll().toString());
```

The output is always first log is empty, and second contains the value, even if I simple reload the fragment.

I'm not sure what I've got wrong, I'm not that experienced with using SharedPreferences.

**In Base Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    sp = new SP(this);
    ...
}

public SP getSP() {
    return sp;
}
```

**SP.java**

```
public SP(Context ctx) {
    sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void storeValue(int type, String key, Object value, Long cacheTime) {
    spe = sp.edit();
    switch (type) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            spe.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
            break;
        case STRING:
            spe.putString(key, (String) value);
            break;
        case LONG:
            spe.putLong(key, (Long) value);
        case INTEGER:
            spe.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            spe.putFloat(key, (Float) value);
            break;
    }


    if (cacheTime != null) {
        spe.putLong(key+TIME_KEY, cacheTime);
    }
    spe.commit();
}

public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
    return sp.getAll();
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I've got wrong here?

If you need anything else posting let me know.

Comment: Does your LogCat have any other information in it? Any warnings or exceptions?

Comment: Nope, no errors at all

Comment: Are you clearing your application data at all inbetween?  Because that will wipe out sharedpreferences.

Comment: Nope, I'm simply rotating my device to get that line of code to run again.

Comment: Have you tried using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`? I wouldn't think it would change anything, but you never know.

Comment: A-HA! That works, thank you :). Post this up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just implemented your version, using the SP class as you provided it, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm an idiot, in my Fragment at the very top I was clearing all the SharedPreferences (this debugging something earlier) and forgot to remove the clear -.- haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was I was clearing the preferences at the top of my code when I was debugging something earlier, and forgot to remove the clear before this.

Comment: I mean honestly, I was doing the same shit. Cleared the sharedPrefs on logout button click and was expecting it to return the data on next login. That's why we all need to take breaks!